# KeyListener for multiplayer game with keys being pressed at the same time?

Tags: java, key, keylistener

I am writing a Two Player snake game. The Arrow Keys respond to one snake and the WASD Keys respond to the other. However I have noticed in my code that if one key for each snake is pressed at the same exact time only one snake turns. I have two KeyListeners that contain an array of the four keys it should be responding to .

```
class PlayerKeyPressListener implements KeyListener {

    // Set of currently pressed keys
    private final Set<Integer> pressed; 
    private int keyEvent[];
    private Color c;
    private int i;

    public PlayerKeyPressListener(int[] a, Color col, int i) {
        super();
        pressed = new HashSet<Integer>();
        keyEvent = a;
        c = col;
        this.i = i;
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(!(pressed.contains(keyEvent[0]) || pressed.contains(keyEvent[1]) 
                || pressed.contains(keyEvent[2]) || pressed.contains(keyEvent[3])))
            pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
        proccessKey(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
        pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/* Not used */ }

    public void proccessKey(int key){
        if(canTurn[i]) {    
            int d = grid.getDirection(c);
            if(key == keyEvent[0]) {
                if(d == 360)

                    grid.setDirection(d - 90, c); //Sets the direction of the snake with the specified color 
                else if(d == 180)
                    grid.setDirection(d + 90, c);
            }
            else if(key == keyEvent[1]) {
                if(d == 360)
                    grid.setDirection(d + 90, c);
                else if(d == 180)
                    grid.setDirection(d - 90, c);
            }
            else if(key == keyEvent[2]) {
                if(d == 90)
                    grid.setDirection(d - 90, c);
                else if(d == 270)
                    grid.setDirection(d + 90, c);
            }
            else if(key == keyEvent[3]) {
                if(d == 90)
                    grid.setDirection(d + 90, c);
                else if(d == 270)
                    grid.setDirection(d - 90, c);
            }
            canTurn[i] = false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Heres is where they get constructed:

```
int[] a = {KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN};
    int[] b = {KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S};
    this.addKeyListener(new PlayerKeyPressListener(a, Color.blue, 0));
    this.addKeyListener(new PlayerKeyPressListener(b, Color.red, 1));
```

Is there a way to make it more responsive for two players?

Comment: For which player does the snake move if the keys are pressed at the same time? For the first or the second? Or is it random?

Comment: Maybe it is because only one of them is being notified of the key press, can you try to move both key processors into one processKey(..) method?